How can I comply with Apple’s Guideline 3.1.1 if my app sells digital products but does not use in-app purchase?
Apple has rejected my app submission because it includes digital products or services that can be purchased using payment methods other than Apple's in-app purchase system, which violates their guidelines. How to solve this ..
#Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase
We noticed that your app includes or accesses paid digital content, services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which is not appropriate for the App Store. Specifically:

The services/packages can be purchased in the app using payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

i dont use in app purchase how to solve this
